# Ether Forward and Token Sweep Contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, remix

I've written a simple ether forwarding contract coupled with a sweep function which when called automatically, sweeps all tokens of specified token contract address to pre-defined recipient addresses.

Would like to seek solidity experts and audit assistance to vet thru the integrity of the code and if it's "relatively" safe to be used in production.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16; //declare solidity version to use

//Standard interface functions for erc20 token contracts
contract ERC20 {
    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint balance);
    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success);
}

contract SweepFunds {
    
    //address declaration
    address payable public merchant = RECIPIENT_ADDR; //merchant account
    address payable public admin = ADMIN_ADDR; //admin account
    
    //Events Logging
    event LogForwardedEther(uint total, address indexed merchant, uint merchVal, address indexed admin, uint adminFee);
    event LogForwardedToken(uint total, address indexed merchant, uint merchVal, address indexed admin, uint adminFee, address indexed token);

    //Fallback function; Gets called when Ether is deposited, and forwards it to merchant and admin
    function() external payable {
        transferFunds(msg.value);
    }

    //It is possible that funds were sent to this address before the contract was deployed; flush those funds to the designated addresses.
    function flushEther() public payable {
        uint ethBal = address(this).balance;
        transferFunds(ethBal);
    }
    
    //Sweep tokens method by specifying token contract address and amount.
    function sweepTokens(address _token) public {
        transferFunds(_token);
    }

    //General transfer funds function (Ether)
    function transferFunds(uint _value) private {
        require(_value > 0);
        uint _fee = (NUMERATOR*_value)/(DENOMINATOR*100);
        
        //Perform Ether transfer method
        emit LogForwardedEther(_value, merchant, _value - _fee, admin, _fee);
        merchant.transfer(_value - _fee);
        admin.transfer(_fee);
    }
    
    //General transfer funds function (Token)
    function transferFunds(address _token) private {
        uint _value = ERC20(_token).balanceOf(address(this));
        require(_value > 0);
        uint _fee = (NUMERATOR*_value)/(DENOMINATOR*100);
            
        //Perform Token transfer method
        emit LogForwardedToken(_value, merchant, _value - _fee, admin, _fee, _token);
        ERC20(_token).transfer(merchant, _value - _fee);
        ERC20(_token).transfer(admin, _fee);
    }
} //end of SweepFunds contract
```

The above contract will be programatically generated by substituting the following strings with values:

- RECIPIENT_ADDR
- ADMIN_ADDR
- NUMERATOR
- DENOMINATOR

## Example

### *Scenario 1*

If fee is 1.5% (NUMERATOR: 3, DENOMINATOR: 2), and 100 ether was sent to the contract address; 98.5 ether will be automatically forwarded to RECIPIENT_ADDR, whereas 1.5 ether will be sent to the ADMIN_ADDR.

### *Scenario 2*

If fee is 1.5% (NUMERATOR: 3, DENOMINATOR: 2), and 100 USDT token was sent to the contract address; 98.5 USDT will be automatically forwarded to RECIPIENT_ADDR, whereas 1.5 USDT will be sent to the ADMIN_ADDR by calling the sweep function, specifying the contract address USDT token contract address.

So far it has been working fine; please let me know if you discover any vulnerabilities or any recommendations are much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should set a constructor for these variables:

- RECIPIENT_ADDR
- ADMIN_ADDR
- NUMERATOR
- DENOMINATOR

And maybe setters/getters for these variables, to add the possibility to edit them afterward.

Adding **Safemath** and **Ownership** from OpenZeppelin's library might be a good idea.

SafeMath to protect from overflows and Ownership provides basic authorization control functions, and allows transferring Ownership of contracts!

Should also check if (_fee > _value).

Comment: Thanks for the respond @Adam; However i have some questions below.

1. The reason i did not make those variables editable is because i do not want even the owner to be able to manipulate the smart contract, since it will be holding erc20 token funds.
2. Wouldn't adding Safemath increase the transaction size/network fee?
3. I won't be using Ownership as i do not see there's a need to since variables are all set (recipient addresses and fee) and should not be modified.

Comment: 1. Yes, but by saying that you're assuming that your wallet or the ones belonging to the RECIPIENT or ADMIN can't be compromised? What, therefore, should be done in this situation? Redeploy the contract? And what to do with users who will continue to send funds to the old(hacked) contract?
2. You're multiplying and dividing, you also have a number that you didn't get from msg.value to multiply or divide by, so based just on that smart contract, I'd be inclined to use SafeMath because otherwise, it could impact value. Resultant, your token will returns unexpected results.

Comment: 3. I agree that once these variables are set, they shouldn't be modified, but in terms of security and vulnerabilities, I encourage you to use it. Unless you can use AgentRole contracts to separate Owner privileges to Agent's ones.

I'm just answering your question, but I agree that if the smart contract is used the way it should be, no major problems should be expected. But you agree that it is very important to note the worst case scenario? :)

Comment: Thanks alot for your input Adam; truly appreciate your explanation! On a separate note, is there a way for me to reference an already deployed SafeMath.sol in all my SweepFunds.sol contract? That way i only have to deploy one SafeMath.sol and as many SweepFunds.sol as necessary, reducing gas cost.

Comment: You're very welcome. In short, a library is a reusable piece of code that is deployed once and shared many times, and it is more optimal in terms of gas cost when the contract is used as a library.
Besides, SafeMath's functions are all declared as internal, it means that the library doesn't have to be deployed.